# Query for records which have the city length > 20

Tags: soql

I am looking for a way to query all leads which have the length of city__c > 20 characters in SOQL.

I cant seem to find anything like a length() in SOQL. Any workarounds? Or am i missing something obvious on the documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create a new formula filed of type NUMBER and insert a simple formula to it that calculates a length of the string:

```
LEN(Street__c)
```

[LEN Formula](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEN)

Then you can query on this field:

```
Select ... From ...  Where FormulaField___c > 20
```

Answer (score 32):

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE (NOT Username LIKE '___')
```

The above SOQL query will return all user rows where the username is not 3 characters.

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Username LIKE '______'
```

The above SOQL query will return all user rows where the username is 5 characters.

Comment: I was surprised to see the positive scenario work, but the negative results in a malformed query (not like). Are you sure that works ?

Comment: Thank you for this information, Mark. FYI I had to put parentheses around the negative to make it work: (NOT Username Like '___')

Comment: Nice find! This definitely works.

Comment: If you are looking for greater than you can use LIKE '_____%' (<-- greater than 5).